# How do you differentiate between '0' and 'no data' on a graph?

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables, data, graphs

I am working on platform that shows data on a graph over a period of weeks. Right now, weeks with no data and weeks when there is data but the property is 0 are shown visually the same.

On hover, it's easy to differentiate on the tooltip, as in one I am saying 'Dataset 1: 0' or 'No data' but I am wondering if there is anything else I can do so that you can differentiate at a glance?

Comment: What type of graph are you trying to display this for?  It would help if you include an image or link to a similar style of graph and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on the exact type of graph that you're displaying.

If you have **visual control**, you can show an **interrupted graph** in a number of ways.  My personal favourite is to **grey out** that section of the graph and not show any visual values.  However, in cases where I haven't had control, I've used an **invalid value** (usually something small and negative) and **labelled that point on the graph as "no data"**.  It's not nearly as visually appealing as some other options, but it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

You can display available values not only via tooltips, but also permanently. For "no data" you can use some indicator like "-", or "#", or "#NV".

You can show it also by a graph. If no data are available, interrupt the graph, like MS Excel. Suppose we have following case:

- Week 1: Data available
- Week 2: Data available
- Week 3: Data available
- Week 4: Data available
- Week 5: Data available
- Week 6: No data
- Week 7: Data available
- Week 8: Data available
- Week 9: Data available

Then you draw graph from week 1 to week 5. Then interrupt it. Then draw graph from week 7 to week 9.

In such approach it doesn't matter, if data value is 0. Important is, that the graph is drawn also for 0 value and it should be distinguishable from the X axis.